# Spring boot jpa and ms sql update issues

Tags: sql-server, jpa, spring-boot

I’m working on a REST web service and I want to migrate from “postgres” database and PHP (the existing web service), to microsoft sql server 2012 and spring boot. So,  I have generated entities using Netbeans IDE from the existing “postgres” database.

Here’s an example of  a generated entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a"),
              @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a WHERE a.id = :id"),
              @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findByLabel", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a WHERE a.label = :label"),
              @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findByType", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a WHERE a.type = :type"),
              @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findByDateOperation", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a WHERE a.dateOperation = :dateOperation"),
              @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findByStatut", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a WHERE a.statut = :statut"),
              @NamedQuery(name = "Activite.findByIsDeleted", query = "SELECT a FROM Activite a WHERE a.isDeleted = :isDeleted") })
public class Activite implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       @Id
       @Basic(optional = false)
       @Column(nullable = false)
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Integer id;
       @Column(length = 255)
       private String label;
```

This application.properties file from my spring boot project :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XXXX
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

The web service work as expected if “spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto” is set to “create”. But I get this error when I changed it to update or validate which is what I want to do.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
       at de.cynapsys.rsu.RsuApplication.main(RsuApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
       ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing table metadata
       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.locateTableInNamespace(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Un nom d'objet ou de colonne est manquant ou vide. Pour les instructions SELECT INTO, vérifiez si chaque colonne a un nom. Pour les autres instructions, recherchez des noms d'alias vides. Les alias définis sous la forme " " ou [] ne sont pas autorisés. Remplacez l'alias par un nom valide.
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:36) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2495) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2500) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setCatalog(SQLServerConnection.java:2851) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.switchCatalogs(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:333) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetFromStoredProc(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:284) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetWithProvidedColumnNames(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:311) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getTables(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:498) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.locateTableInNamespace(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
       ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where exactly are you running the `Select INTO` query?

Comment: This  query is launched after runing the server and when i use "update"in this instruction " spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update "